# Given two rectangles, return another rectangle representing the overlapping area

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I need to create an intersect method for rectangle class, that takes a rectangle and returning another rectangle representing the overlapping area.

for example, given:

[image]

if they are overlapping I should return a rectangle of point (400,420) width = 50 height = 60.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: tried asking on SO... stuck waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `CGRectIntersection` function, it will return the intersection of two `CGRect` instances:

```
CGRect CGRectIntersection (
   CGRect r1,
   CGRect r2
);
```

There are quite a few useful functions detailed here:

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/12/useful-core-graphics-functions.html